# Android custom Camera application crashes as it starts "unfortuantely stopped"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera

I am trying to build my own custom camera application I have learn through the Android developers Group about how to code the whole application but as soon as I launch the camera it crashes I don't know what is the problem here is my code:

```
package com.example.tapeit;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Files.FileColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements Camera.PictureCallback {

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
String TAG = "TapeIt";
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
Button captureButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.preview_layout);

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(preview);

    captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            });

}


private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context){
    if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}


public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return c;
}


private PictureCallback mPicture  = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " );
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};


private static File getOutputMediaFile(int mediaTypeImage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraApp");

    if(! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if(! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
             Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
             return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +"IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    return mediaFile;
}


@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " );
        return;
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

}

And here is my preview Class:

```
package com.example.tapeit;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.hardware.Camera;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private Camera mCamera;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
String TAG = "TapeIt";

public CameraPreview (Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        return;
    }

    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    //You should make here changes when the device is rotated or when any other change
    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    //mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();


    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview" + e.getMessage());
    }


}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

My manifest uses all the permision here they are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />       

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tapeit.CameraActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My logcat in the console is posted here:

```
04-04 11:19:32.010: D/AndroidRuntime(21270): Shutting down VM
04-04 11:19:32.010: W/dalvikvm(21270): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40eb72a0)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tapeit/com.example.tapeit.CameraActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3439)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3310)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3255)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3231)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at com.example.tapeit.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:39)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
04-04 11:19:32.010: E/AndroidRuntime(21270):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: "unfortunately stopped" is the message for the user, the developer is getting a nice stacktrace in logcat. Please add that to your question / have a look it it yourself

Comment: without the stacktrace everything is just best guess - my guess is that you're getting a null pointer exception on the camera object...

Comment: Please post your error logs..!!!!

Comment: Sorry guys I just posted them, please help m. Appreciate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preview.addView(preview);
```

You are attempting to add the `FrameLayout` to itself. This will not work.

Presumably, the parameter should be `mPreview`.

You may wish to use more distinctive names for variables, such as not having both `preview` and `mPreview`.

Comment: I just did that will test it now and see how it goes !

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare it worked just perfect I just have to adjust the screen orientation because the image is distorted.

Comment: Man you were faster than me on that!